# symfony3 long foreach exec time

Tags: php, symfony

I got file upload listener which uploads a file, parses it and puts data to a DB through Doctrine. The script is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
use CommonBundle\Entity\Classifiers;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostPersistEvent;
use CommonBundle\Entity\ClassifierPhrase;
use CommonBundle\Entity\ClassifierSubject;

class UploadListener
{
/**
 * @var ObjectManager
 */
private $om;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
{
    $this->om = $om;
}

public function onUpload(PostPersistEvent $event)
{
    $type = $event->getRequest()->get('type');
    if($event->getRequest()->get('classifier_id')){
        $classifier_id = $event->getRequest()->get('classifier_id');
        $classifier = $this->om->getRepository('CommonBundle:Classifiers')->findOneBy(['id' => $classifier_id]);
    }

    $file = $event->getFile();
    $contents = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
    $entries = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $contents);

        foreach($entries as $entry) {
            $time_start = microtime(true); //start here
            //some parsing logic
            $this->om->persist($phrase);
            $this->om->flush();
            $time_end = microtime(true);
            $execution_time = round(($time_end - $time_start)/60, 4);
            file_put_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\perfomance.txt', 'time: ' . $execution_time. ' phrase: '.$entry[0].PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
//takes about 0.005 sec per entry
        }
    $response = [$event->getResponse(), 'success' => true];
    return $response;
  }
}
```

So upon markup it takes about 0.005 sec/entry to work. I got 5000 entries in my file and php max_execution directive for 300 sec and it cannot process all entries for 5 minutes. Also during script execution I see how the entries are added to my log file, and I see that it is adding entry by entry to it, but very slowly (about 20 entries per sec). So it is waiting for something during entries parsing inside my `foreach` loop. Any ideas how to profile the script and why it may be so long lasting would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: who is `$phrase`?

Comment: php and the doctrine entity manager is just not all that great at batch operations.  There are lots of similar questions out there with various hints.  Instead of flushing after each persist consider flushing every 100 insertions.  That should help a bit.  Of course a file_put_contents inside the loop is not helping.  And make sure you are running in production mode with xdebug disabled.

Comment: thank you for pointing out. I have removed `flush()` outside but it did not help much. `file_put_contents` is there only for logging purposes, script does not work fast without it in prod. Every foreach cycle from start to `file_put_contents` takes 0.005 sec in average which is satisfactory for me and I think the issue is not inside it (thats why I have removed parsing logic from here). Many there are some more debugging tools that would help to figure out the problem or similar questions?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

> An ORM tool is not primarily well-suited for mass inserts, updates or deletions. Every RDBMS has its own, most effective way of dealing with such operations and if the options outlined below are not sufficient for your purposes we recommend you use the tools for your particular RDBMS for these bulk operations.

This means that you should not use Doctrine ORM for bulk inserts. Simple as that.
Use Doctrine DBAL and SQL instead.